# problem caused due to changing the size of array , during finding the frequency of charcters

Tags: c++, arrays, size

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    int hash[256];

    getline(cin, s);

    int max = 0;
    char ch;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        hash[s[i]]++;
        if (hash[s[i]] > max)
        {
            max = hash[s[i]];
            ch = s[i];
        }
        else if (hash[s[i]] == max && ch > s[i])
        {
            ch = s[i];
        }
    }
    cout << ch << " " << max;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is for finding the the max frequency of characters from given string. The problem is the code works fine when I initalize the array to zero (`int hash[256] = {0}`) (256 because it's max no. of characters possible), but if I don't the program doesn't output the right answer, furthermore if I change it to (`int hash[3000];`) the code runs fine too. I am not getting what is the problem arises when  I change the size.

Comment: Your mistake seems to be that you think bad programs should not work. Unfortunately that is not true. Bad programs have *undefined behaviour*, and working is one possible result (as is not working). In short good programs are guaranteed to work, but it's not guaranteed that bad programs will not work.

Comment: Why is the code not working when you don't initialise the array surprising?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think the OP's surprise is that the larger uninitialised array does work.

Comment: The problem is that C++ requires you to initialize everything before it's used. And just because an array of a particular size appears to be initialized to 0 does not really make it so, and it might be initialized today but tomorrow when you run the same program it crashes because it no longer is. That's because tomorrow [all the demons decided to finally fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), and not today.

Comment: `int hash[256]` gives an array of 256 uninitialised `int`s. The first thing done with any element is `hash[s[i]]]++` which accesses one of those uninitialised elements (undefined behaviour) and increments it. Giving the wrong answer is one possible symptom of that. Increasing array size does not remove the undefined behaviour.  "undefined behaviour" actually means (semi-formally) "the C++ standard does not define what happens" and (informally) "anything can happen".   The thing is, nothing prevents a program with undefined behaviour from *appearing* to work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  C++ does not require initialisation of everything before use.   It leaves behaviour undefined (no diagnostic required) if things are not initialised, and the values are accessed.   There is no prohibition on code having undefined behaviour in the standard.

Comment: @Peter but the program does works fine when , i write int hash[3000] but didnt initalise it. thats what confusing me , if initialising is the only problem , then it shouldnt work .

Comment: @HarshitGupta - The behaviour is undefined.   That is not the same as "is required to not work".     You are equating the two, and in that you are mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: An array in C++ will not be initialized and can contain arbitrary data. Using uninitialized values will result in undefined behavior.

Why does changing the size the array changes anything?

When you invoke undefined behavior **anything** can happen. Technically deleting all your files would be a "correct" implementation.

In this case I suppose the compiler will store the larger array in a different place and this place happens to contain zeros.

**Edit**

There is one exception to the initialization: global arrays (and variables) will be always initialized with zero at the start of the program.

Comment: so can it be possible that , the unitialised array just works fine one time and it can cause problem when i run it again ??

Comment: yes it absolutely can.
Because of things as address space randomization you can even observe difference between different runs.